# how to access search click event on flutter dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I am using dropdown search to list data. I want to access the click event of this dropdown but I can't. How can I access

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Lütfen Seçim Yapın",
  ),
  mode: Mode.DIALOG,
  showSearchBox: true,
  items: _items.map((e) => e.TASIMANO!).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    _mystate = value;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged` will trigger when the item is tapped. Also you can use `dropdownBuilder` with a gesture widget.

```dart
dropdownBuilder: (context, selectedItem) => GestureDetector(
  // behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    print("tapped $selectedItem");
  },
  child: Text(
    selectedItem ?? '',
  ),
),
onChanged: (value) {
  print(value);
},
```

Comment: If you are referring button itself, wrap with  `GestureDetector` . and include `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,`